# Can I safely move a Git repository between machines with different Git version installed?

Tags: git

Say I have a client pc with Git version 1.6 and a server with Git v.1.7.1.

On the client I create a bare Git repo,

Later on, I move this repo from the client machine to the server one where Git v.1.7.1 is installed.

What is wrong with this picture?

And, eventually, what is the best practice for moving a Git repo between machines with different Git version installed?

Comment: Why wouldn't you clone from one bare repo to another, and avoid meta-incompatibilities? (That really is a question, as opposed to a passive-aggressive suggestion.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with that picture. The repository format hasn't changed.

About the worst thing that could happen: if you moved a repo to a computer with an *older* version of Git, it's possible you might have parameters in .git/config which didn't exist yet in the older version, and they'd be ignored. (Assuming by "move" you mean directly copying files - even this wouldn't be an issue if you were just cloning, since that doesn't copy .git/config.)

So... best practice? Just do it however is convenient.